# ASP.NET Core simple DB cleaner background service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In an application there is a table for one-time-passwords (OTP) which will be sent to users via SMS. These OTPs are needed for a maximum of two hours in order to detect abusing behaviours.

A simple DB cleaner will delete these rows (`DeleteAsync` is from [this library](https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-batch-delete)):

```
public class DbCleaner : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogService logService;

    public DbCleaner(
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        ILogService logService)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        this.logService = logService;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IdentityDbContext>();

            var otpDeleted = await dbContext.OTP
                .IgnoreQueryFilters()
                .Where(x => x.CreationTime.AddHours(2) >= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
                .DeleteAsync();

            await LogOperationAsync(otpDeleted);

            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1), stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                // application is shutting down
                // ignore this
            }
        }
    }

    private Task LogOperationAsync(int otpCount)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

On every publish, the timer will be reset which is fine for this project.

Comment: Why don't you use a database job for this?

Comment: Everything is code first

Comment: @Parsa99 you could implement the proper procedures to create and modify the sql jobs from code first approach, and reuse them from you code.

Comment: Can you please share a resource? I am using EF Core 6 with Npgsql (PostgreSQL 14).

Comment: @Parsa99 npsql is a bit different, however, you could read about available job scheduler and see how you can reuse it as store procedure from your code. https://severalnines.com/blog/overview-job-scheduling-tools-postgresql/

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the opposite of what you want:

```
.Where(x => x.CreationTime.AddHours(2) >= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
```

This would be a lot easier to read with a named variable like:

```
var deleteBefore = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2);
.Where(x => x.CreationTime < deleteBefore)
```

It would also be good to have the 2 hours pulled out into a named constant at class level. Another thing to consider is having the expiration time explicitly stored as a column, instead of having the code compute it from the creation time.